# imposing a check : don't proceed if there is already a string in column number 0

Tags: java, string

Through the following code i look to club all the alphabets with starting with the same name into one array column and in the second column i want to keep the sum of the numbers associated with the alphabets.

For example :

```
array_1 = { {"bat","1"},
            {"rat","2"},
            {"ball","3"},
            {"run","4"},
            {"lizard","5"}
          }

into array_2 = { {"b","4"},
                 {"r","6"},
                 {"l",5}
                }
```

The following code gives half correct results. The problem when it reaches *`ball`* it again adds the next alphabet starting with `b` and stores it as a separate value. the problem is line number 42.I have marked that.How should i impose a check that it doesn't add the number of the alphabet once it has added.

```
package keylogger;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArrayTester {

private static int finalLength=0;
private static String firstAlphabet[][];
private String data[][] = { 
                               {"Nokia" , "7"},
                               {"Blackberry" , "1"},
                               {"Nimbus","10"},
                               {"Apple","19"},
                               {"Ami","21"},
                               {"Bug","35"},
                               {"Native","200"},
                               {"zebra","100"},
                               {"Nine","9"}

                          };  

public void calculator() {
   try {  
    // traverse the whole array
    firstAlphabet = new String[data.length][data.length]; // set the length of firstAlphabet array

    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        firstAlphabet[i][0] = data[i][0].substring( 0, 1); // get the first alphabet
        firstAlphabet[i][1] = data[i][1];
        int k = i+1;
        int v = k;
        int t=0;
        for(int j=0;j<data.length-v;j++) {
            System.out.println("Inner for loop" + j);
            String s = data[k][0];
// line 42:
            if(firstAlphabet[i][0].compareToIgnoreCase(s.substring(0, 1))==0) { 
               System.out.println("If statement");
               firstAlphabet[i][0] = s.substring(0, 1);
               Integer z = Integer.parseInt(data[k][1]) + Integer.parseInt(firstAlphabet[i][1]);
               firstAlphabet[i][1] = z.toString();                   
            }
            k++;
        }   
    }               
  }catch(Exception exc) {
     exc.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayTester o = new ArrayTester();
    o.calculator();
    for(String s[] : firstAlphabet) {
        for(String x : s) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
Inner for loop0

Inner for loop1

If statement

Inner for loop2

Inner for loop3

Inner for loop4

Inner for loop5

If statement

Inner for loop6

Inner for loop7

If statement

Inner for loop0

Inner for loop1

Inner for loop2

Inner for loop3

If statement

Inner for loop4

Inner for loop5

Inner for loop6

Inner for loop0

Inner for loop1

Inner for loop2

Inner for loop3

If statement

Inner for loop4

Inner for loop5

If statement

Inner for loop0

If statement

Inner for loop1

Inner for loop2

Inner for loop3

Inner for loop4

Inner for loop0

Inner for loop1

Inner for loop2

Inner for loop3

Inner for loop0

Inner for loop1

Inner for loop2

Inner for loop0

Inner for loop1

If statement

Inner for loop0

N

226

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

B

36

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

N

219

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

A

40

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

A

21

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

B

35

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

N

209

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

z

100

null

null

null

null

null

null

null

N

9

null

null

null

null

null

null

null
```

If we notice the sum associated with the alphabets is correct. The only problem is repetition. i.e for example N=219 which is 200+19

Comment: It probably would help if you add the expected result for your example. Your explanation is a bit confused - mostly because I've no idea what "start with a name" means, letter presumably? But then the solution is obvious.

Comment: Have you considered using another data structure for storing the sums, for instance, a `Map<String, Integer>` ?

Comment: @Voo I mentioned that in my question

Comment: @program Oh I see, sorry misunderstood the question. Just use a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` then as Xavi proposes

Comment: just changed the title !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repetition is caused because you dont mark already selected Alphabet as dirty.

So in the first loop itself N has got a final count but with your current logic when Nimbus comes under itertion, you will do the entire processing since you havent marked N as dirty.

```
public void calculator() {
        List<String> marked = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            // traverse the whole array
            firstAlphabet = new String[data.length][2]; // set the length of first Alphabet array
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                String firstLetter = data[i][0].substring(0, 1);
                if(marked.contains(firstLetter)){
                    continue;
                }
                marked.add(firstLetter);
                firstAlphabet[i][0] = firstLetter; // get the first alphabet
                firstAlphabet[i][1] = data[i][1];
                int k = i + 1;
                int v = k;
                int t = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < data.length - v; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Inner for loop" + j);
                    String s = data[k][0];
                    if (firstAlphabet[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(s.substring(0,
                            1))) { // line 42
                        System.out.println("If statement");
                        firstAlphabet[i][0] = s.substring(0, 1);
                        Integer z = Integer.parseInt(data[k][1])
                                + Integer.parseInt(firstAlphabet[i][1]);
                        firstAlphabet[i][1] = z.toString();
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i asked that only  !:) How should i make an alphabet dirty

Comment: updated my post, though a better data structure like others have suggested would resolve such issues

Comment: is there a way to calculate the length of the final array ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you can do is the following:

```
// words is an array of tuples (word, frequency); that should probably be a class in your java code
// sums is a HashMap<Character, Integer>
foreach word, frequency in words:
     letter = word[0]
     sums[letter] = sums[letter] + frequency
```

Should be straightforward to write in Java - and also faster and simpler than your current code. The only thing you have to do is check whether `sums[letter]` already exists, if not initialize it with `frequency` - too bad that Java doesn't offer a DefaultDict for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Use a more convenient data structure, such as a `Map<Character, Integer>`.
2. If changing data structures is not suitable to you, you could also sort the input array before starting the iteration, using a custom `Comparator`. See [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

   ```
   Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
       public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
           Character letter1 = o1[0].charAt(0);
           Character letter2 = o2[0].charAt(0);
           return letter1.compareTo(letter2);
       }
   });
   ```